# Arrow function for onClick is updating parameters of all instances to latest usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick

I am using an arrow function to set the onClick function for a button, the problem is, this piece of code gets called multiple times as I have a lot of buttons, and the arrow function is changing the input parameter for the onClick function of all buttons to latest value of input parameter.

```
meta_data = await meta_response.json();
      var local_stack = []
      var temp_input = null
        var num = meta_data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {   
            console.log(meta_data[i]["name"])
            if (meta_data[i]["type"] != "file"){
                await this.menu_gen(url,meta_data[i]["name"],[])
                //this.menuShow();
                //local_stack.push(meta_data[i]["name"])
                console.log(this.state.change_state)
                elementlist.push(<Dropdown drop="left">
                <Dropdown.Toggle drop="left" variant="success" className='btn-secondary mr-3 btn-menu2 btn-block' id = "bgdiv">
                {meta_data[i]["name"]}
                </Dropdown.Toggle>
                <Dropdown.Menu id = "bgdiv2">{this.state.change_state}</Dropdown.Menu></Dropdown>)
        }
            else
            { await local_stack.push(url + "/" + meta_data[i]["name"])
              temp_input =   url + "/" + meta_data[i]["name"]
                elementlist.push(<Dropdown.Item id='bgdiv' className='mr-3'><button type='button' value={temp_input} className='btn btn-secondary mr-3 btn-menu2 btn-block' onClick={() => this.data_load(temp_input)}>
                    {meta_data[i]["name"]}</button></Dropdown.Item>)
            }
        }
        //this.menuShow()
        console.log(elementlist)
        //var deepEqual = require('deep-equal')

        //if(firstflag!=1)
        //return elementlist
        //else if(!deepEqual(this.state.change_state, elementlist)){
        this.setState({ change_state: elementlist });
        this.setState({ extra_flag: false });
```

If this piece of code is called 5 times with 5 different values, say "one", "two", "three". "four", "five", for meta_data[i]["name"], all 5 button onClick functions are receiving only "five" as the input parameter.

Comment: Can you put more relevant code? Maybe use the code blocks?

Comment: Please add more on this code, so we can debug more clearly.

Comment: Hi, I have added more code, hope this provides better context.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `data_load` function?